# Converting 12 hours to 24 hours

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to set automatic events in the calendar through a google form, but when the user submits the form with `13:50:00 PM` it automatically gets converted into `01:50:00 PM` which when I use for creating events in the calendar, it gets created for `AM` timing.

Code I am using to convert 12hr to 24hr

```
    function combineDate(startDate,startTm,endTm)
{
    startDate = '07/07/2022'
    startTm = '00:50:00 AM'
    endTm = '03:00:00 PM'
     const strDate = startDate.split('/')
     const dt = parseInt(strDate[0])
     const mnth = parseInt(strDate[1])-1
     const year = parseInt(strDate[2])
     startTm = convertTime(startTm)
     endTm = convertTime(endTm)
     const strTime = startTm.split(':')
     const sthr = parseInt(strTime[0])
     const stMn = parseInt(strTime[1])
     const endTime = endTm.split(':')
     const ethr = parseInt(endTime[0])
     const etMn = parseInt(endTime[1])
     console.log({startDT : new Date(year,mnth,dt,sthr,stMn,0),endDT : new Date(year,mnth,dt,ethr,etMn,0)})
     return {startDT : new Date(year,mnth,dt,sthr,stMn,0),endDT : new Date(year,mnth,dt,ethr,etMn,0) }  
}



function convertTime(s)
{
   var arr = s.split(":")
   if(arr[2].includes('PM'))
   {
     if(arr[0] != '12')
     {
        var hr = parseInt(arr[0]) + 12
        return String(hr) + ':' + arr[1]
     }
     else{
       return s
     }
   }
   else{    
      return s;
   }
```

}

Comment: So if hours > 12, PM part should be dropped automatically?

Comment: Yes, it should convert it to 24 hour, i just need `hour` and `minute`, like if user input `01:50:00 PM` it should convert into `13:50:00 PM` or just `13:50`

Comment: That was the idea for implementing actually. :) Your current code doesn't check this condition; add this and it should work.

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks, can you check the updated code, is it the right approach, because I checked for few timing, it works

Answer (score 0):

[Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12226005/khan) was able to apply the solution mentioned by [raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow) by adding a conditional statement to verify if the hour is above past 12 PM.

This is how the conditional statement was applied:

```
function convertTime(s)
{
   var arr = s.split(":")
   if(arr[2].includes('PM'))
   {
     if(arr[0] != '12')
     {
        var hr = parseInt(arr[0]) + 12
        return String(hr) + ':' + arr[1]
     }
     else{
       return s
     }
   }
   else{    
      return s;
   }
}
```